# Why are my divs not staying in line?

Tags: html, css, positioning, inline

I am trying to get an ***Input*** and a ***Link*** element to sit side by side inside a ***Div*** element.

I wanted to have the ***Div*** and the ***Link*** to completely fill the ***Div*** element so you cannot *see* the containing ***Div*** around the edges of the ***Input*** and ***Link*** elements.

However if I set the width of my ***Link*** element any wider than **27px** is falls to the next line even though I should have up to **31px** left of the container ***Div*** to fit the ***Link*** element in. Relevent HTML and CSS below...

HTML

```
<section>
        <img src="images/logo11w.png">
        <div name="search">
            <input>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
div[name="search"]{

display: block;
margin: auto;
height: 27px;
width: 572px;
background-color: green;}

input{

display: inline-block;
width: 541px;
height: 27px;
border-style: none;
background-color: yellow;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;}

div[name="search"]>a{
display: inline-block;
width: 27px;
height: 27px;
background-color: red;
margin: 0;}
```

Could someone explain why my link element cannot be wider that 27px without falling to the next line? I am OK with having the width be only 27px I just wanted to understand why this is happening from a technical standpoint.

Comment: I recomend using Chrome's Inspect Element (or Firebug in FF).  From there you can see exactly why this is happening, make adjustments, and fix your code.  CSS is always a trial and error process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block` displays the whitespace in the actual layout in the rendered html... one whitespace is 4px . so if you want your link to have 31px width, you need to give `margin-left:-4px` or remove the whitespace in the actual layout.

```
<section>
        <img src="images/logo11w.png">
        <div name="search">
            <input><a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

updated fiddle with no white space:
http://jsfiddle.net/x6Mq5/

updated fiddle with `margin-left:-4px;`
http://jsfiddle.net/x6Mq5/1/